# why do SMA50 and SMA200 calculations differ on a 1Y price chart vs 2y price chart

Tags: charts, yahoo-finance

We know that formula for Simple Moving Average (SMA) is the same, no matter what the length of observations period is. However, I don't understand why MA(50,C,MA,0) differs on a 1Y chart when compared to a 2Y chart for same security. For example, when you run this on S&P index as of 2/5/20 using Yahoo charts we get 2,998.20 as SMA50 for 2Y or 5Y observations, whereas the same is 3,217.60 for any period 1Y and under. Anyone knows why this differs ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at what the tick interval is. The tick interval for 1Y is usually 1 day, but the tick interval will typically scale with the date range. The 2Y chart probably has a different tick interval, like 2 days (just a guess based on your observation). This means that the SMA50 would be calculated over 100 days worth of data, while the 1Y is calculated over 50 days worth of data.

Answer (score 0):

In Yahoo charts, the 1Y chart is plotted using daily points, the 2Y chart is using weekly points. That means SMA50 for a 1Y chart is the 50 trading days average, while SMA50 for a 2Y chart is the 50 trading weeks average. That's why they are different.